# Ratchet / When.js: "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined"

Tags: php, zeromq, ratchet

I'm trying to use ratchet for reflecting the changes made to my database realtime.
I used the code of the pusher app (http://socketo.me/docs/push). But i am getting error in that.

The moment I open the client side page :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined                    when.js:900
(anonymous function)                                              when.js:900
(anonymous function)                                              when.js:15
(anonymous function)                                              when.js:900
```

After this I typed: 
conn.subscribe('topic'); //This subscribes the topic.

Now the moment I make changes to this topic, an error pops up where the changes are to be displayed.

Error 2 :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function         [VM] autobahn.min.js (124):66
(anonymous function)                                    [VM] autobahn.min.js (124):66
c._websocket.onmessage                                  [VM] autobahn.min.js (124):66
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *may* be solvable by using the following JavaScript *before* including the `when.js` file:

```
window.define = function(factory) {
    try{ delete window.define; } catch(e){ window.define = void 0; } // IE
    window.when = factory();
};
window.define.amd = {};
```

Then, include your `when.js` file.

Comment: This script may have worked with the library in September 2013 but it probably doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using the when.js without using a module system such as AMD.

The docs explain how to transform the file to work in a browser through use of [browserify](http://browserify.org/), so long as you've done n

#### Browser environments (via browserify)

Since when.js primarily targets modular environments, it doesn't export to the global object (`window` in browsers) by default. You can create your own build of when.js using browserify, if you prefer not to use an AMD or CommonJS loader in your project.

1. `git clone https://github.com/cujojs/when`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run browserify` to generate `build/when.js`

   1. Or `npm run browserify-debug` to build with when/monitor/console enabled
4. `<script src="path/to/when/build/when.js"></script>`

   1. `when` will be available as `window.when`
   2. Other modules will be available as sub-objects/functions, e.g. `window.when.fn.lift`, `window.when.sequence`.  See the full sub-namespace list in the browserify build file